# Idiomatic way for combining redux toolkit slices and reducers

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

**Techstack**: React, redux, redux toolkit (by extension Immer).

**Use case** - I am trying combine slices. The slices are for independent pieces of state whose interface is defined by a third party library.

I am trying to do something unconventional. It has been a long time since I did any serious work in React or redux, so I might have missed out on some useful libraries that have come by. I have done the initial scan and have not found anything suiting my taste. However, suggestions are always welcome.

Also, this is the first time I am seriously trying to use typescript. So though I have done my homework, my brain is yet to be wired with all the typescript idioms and goodies.

I don't want to give up on any of the technologies which I am using just for this use case.

This use case will keep repeating. I am sure others in the community have faced similar problems.

As typescript is more or less syntactic sugar on top of ES6, there are a lot of obvious limitations which make such use cases tricky to handle.

```
export type Slices<T, U> = Record<keyof T, Slice<U>>;
export type Reducers<T,U> = Record<keyof T, CaseReducerWithPrepare<U, PayloadAction<any, string, never, never>>>;

export function combiner<T> (name : string, state : T, slices : Slices<T, any>,  reducers : Reducers<T, any>) 
    : Slice<T, SliceCaseReducers<T>, string> {
        let options : ValidateSliceCaseReducers<T, SliceCaseReducers<T>> = {}; 
        options = produce(options, draft => {
            for(let key in slices) {
                draft[key]=slices[key].reducer;
            }
            for(let key in slices) {
                draft[key]=reducers[key];
            }    
        })
        return createSlice({
            name,
            initialState : state,
            reducers : options
        })
};
```

I am doing some risky type related stuff here. But the code is going to be buried deep. As this is not a part of the contractual API, I might get away with doing a bit of crazy.

However, if I can find an idiomatic way of doing this, I can promote this logic upstream and may even be able to open source it.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**: Adding further clarifications

There are 2 outputs from Slice, CaseReducers and a single reducer, which I took to mean a reducer that combines all the reducers that were provided to the slice. I am yet to get through to running unit tests for the code above in my code. A little lost in other bugs that are hiding whether the code above will actually work or not. I thought it was at one point.

Do note that the code above is representational of the actual code.

Here is an example schema

```
{
   "key1" : {
       "A" : "SomeA",
       "B" : "SomeB"
    },
   "key2" : {
       "A" : "SomeA",
       "B" : "SomeB"
    }
}
```

As you can see the schema for `key1` and `key2` are the same. So I would want to have the same bit of slice code which takes care of `key1` and `key2` parameterised to deal with the correct part of the state.

Again this example is representational. The state object I am dealing with is large and has depth.

Also, the state object has been described as 'typescript' interface in a third-party library. I thought I should keep dealing with the same rather than write my own JSON schema. Hence, I am using the `keyof` operator here.

But if I can solve this problem of parameterising correctly, I can significantly reuse code.

Comment: I'm rather confused what you're doing here. Your `produce()` call isn't using the result at all, and `createSlice` is meant to handle updating a chunk of state based specific action types.  "Slice reducers" _are_ the output of `createSlice`, and you wouldn't pass them in to another `createSlice` call.  Are you looking for [the Redux `combineReducers` function](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers) instead?

Comment: @markerikson Thanks for the response. I am glad to have my questions answered by one of the Redux maintainers!

I have updated the code sample to correct the bug you pointed out.

Comment: @markerikson As I mentioned, I am trying to do something unconventional. I am looking at combining the slices. I will update the question further to provide some clarification in next few minutes.

Comment: @markerikson added clarification. Hope it helps explain better what I am trying to do here and whether it is workable (even if it is risky in terms of typing) approach.

Comment: @markerikson as you suggested I could go for combineReducers. If that is the suggestion, I will be able to use createSlice just one level above the leaf. If it is the correct  approach, I will move towards using combineReducers instead of slice. But as I mentioned the nesting *is* deep. And reuse can potentially happen at different depths. Of course each different schema will have its own slice related code.

Comment: Conceptually in the app, what kinds of actions are supposed to result in `state.Key1.A` getting updated, vs `state.Key2.A`? Same action types?  Similar action types but slightly different (ie, `INCREMENT_COUNTER1` vs `INCREMENT_COUNTER2`)?  Completely different actions that are unique to each similar chunk of state?

Comment: @markerikson Same piece of code for now, though I could have different action keys just to ensure there is no confusion as to which part of state is going to get updated when an action is dispatched. That is why I am trying to parameterise the keys over hear. Because it is my understanding that the slice logic will generate action types on the basis of keys.

Comment: @markerikson For simplicity, it is ok to consider the app to be updating the state a bunch of times and there will be a user-initiated action before the state is processed beyond simple mutations.

Conceptually, It is like a large draft of a state. Once the user has completed updating the draft,  he hits "done" button and then the state is submitted for further processing. He could keep updating and then hitting done the way you would update a Google doc or word doc.

Comment: Right, but the issue is that [multiple uses of the same reducer, responding to the same action, will result in different pieces of state being updated the same way](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/reusing-reducer-logic), which is likely not what you want..  Honestly, at this point I think I'd need to see a semi-realistic example of what you're actually trying to do as a CodeSandbox, to be able to give better advice here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211800/discussion-between-user1676688-and-markerikson).